# How to hide the information of shell command will print and save it to a variable?

Tags: shell

I want use `git pull` in my shell script, it print 'Already up-to-date.', but I don't want it be printed. I want to save these message to a variable. How to do this? Thanks very much!

---

update:

`➜ gitvar=$(git checkout alpha)
Already on 'alpha'
➜ echo $gitvar
M   _gg.sh
M   _posts/2018-10-22-about.md`

I want to save "Already on 'alpha'" to variable "gitvar". The $(...) don't. Does this have anything to do with zsh?

---

update:
I'm sorry. I didn't know stdout and stderr before. Thank you for telling me this. 
The answer to the question is that the print of the command may be stdout, or it may be stderr.

   `1 output=$(command)      # stdout only; stderr remains uncaptured
   2 output=$(command 2>&1) # both stdout and stderr will be captured`

Comment: Aside: avoid `git pull` in scripts; use the two Git commands that `git pull` will run, instead. You'll get proper control that way.

Comment: @torek thanks for your comments,  what do you mean, "use the two Git commands"?

Comment: @Eitrigg, `git pull` is `git fetch` + `git merge`. It doesn't do anything you don't get by combining the other two.

Comment: BTW, your "already on alpha" is on stderr, not stdout, which is why it isn't captured... which is what our many, *many* existing knowledgebase entries about the same problem already say. This is also covered in [BashFAQ #2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Auxilus has indicated, you can capture the output of a command within a variable using *command substitution*, e.g. `$(...)`. The output for the command within `$(...)` can then be assigned to a variable, e.g.

```
$ gitvar=$(git pull)
```

Above, the output from `git pull` is now stored in `gitvar`. If you are waning to use this in a log file, then you can prepend the date to the output allowing a chronological log be maintained. A good log date format is `"%b %e %T"` (e.g. `Dec 30 04:36:22`). Creating your `logvar` is a simple matter of preprending the date to the string and adding the content of `gitvar`, e.g.

```
$ logvar="$(date +"%b %e %T") - $gitvar"
$ echo "$logvar"
Dec 30 04:36:36 - already up to date
```

You can then redirect the output to any log of your choice or make use of the original `gitvar` however you need.

Comment: thank you very much, I have try, but it don't work, this is the result: ```➜ gitvar=$(git checkout alpha)
Already on 'alpha'
➜ echo $gitvar
M   _gg.sh
M   _posts/2018-10-22-about.md```

Comment: I don't understand. If you do a `git pull`, it will either report `"Already up-to-date."` or it will return `"remote: Enumerated objects.."` written to `stderr` and a list of files updated. (e.g. `"Updating 6e76e48..0ec1232 Fast-forward..."`) written to `stdout`. Using `$ gitvar=$(git pull)` only captures information written to `stdout`. If you want to capture both, use `$ gitvar=$(git pull 2>&1)` to write both `stdout` and `stderr` to `gitvar`.

Comment: If you don't want some part of the output, you can always use `head` or `tail` to trim lines from the start or end, or `sed` to trim from the middle based on some pattern match.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the standard output of the command to a variable in two ways:

```
a=`git pull`
a=$(git pull)
```

The latter is easier to nest, e.g.:

```
a=$(ls $(pwd))
```

---

However, you should note that the programs usually print the messages on two streams: `stdout` and `stderr`. E.g. `git pull` will print `Already up-to-date` on the `stdout` which would be correctly captured by the commands above. The error messages like `fatal: not a git repository` are printed on the `stderr` stream. In order to capture all output into the variable you need to redirect `stderr` into the `stdout`:

```
a=`git pull 2>&1`
```

The numbers `1` and `2` correspond to `stdout` and `stderr`, accordingly.

Comment: Good answer. Please note that the $(...) notation is today preferred over the backtick.

Comment: Replace `A=$(ls $(PWD))` by `a=$(ls $(pwd))`. `PWD` is a system shell variable, use lowercase variables for your own variable names.

Comment: @WalterA, right, thank you. This example is kind of dumb anyway.

Comment: ...well, in *real* life we'd use `ls "$PWD"`; pointless to spawn a subshell just to run a command that emits a value you already have in a built-in variable anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by

```
var=$(command)
```

and access var such as

```
echo $var
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the bullet therein regarding questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before".